# WebKit Browser javascript callback

Tags: javascript, vb.net, browser, webkit

I have got a vb.net application launching a webkit browser and the vb.net has some functions in it like getting hostname and serial number and launching and killing the osk of the windows tablet.

When the vb.net ran or launched ie the apex application running on ie ran all the javascript (that called the vb.net functions).

The problem is that when IE is used then the css and page styling did not render properly on mobile devices, so we switched to WebKit Browser and everything looks much much better. Now I have a problem in that the javascript doesn't execute.

The javascript used is this:

```
$s("P2_SERIAL",window.external.getSerialNumber());

return 0;
```

Can anyone help me with the WebKit Browser equivalent please?